# Open AirDrop programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa

Which path do I need to enter to open AirDrop in the Finder?

e.g. I can enter `~/` to open my home folder, which path would point to AirDrop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this myself. The path to AirDrop is
`/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Applications/AirDrop.app`

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted to prevent this question from ending up in 'Unanswered' category forever.

Comment: I didnt do that yet since SO told me I would need to wait 2 days to do that. Thanks for the reminder.